# gnupg keyserver configuration

Tags: macos, gnupg

I am on macOS, running `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.10`.

I am trying to use `hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net` as my keyserver. Since `keyserver` option for `gnupg` is deprecated, I add this to `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`:

```
# dirmngr.conf
keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
```

I understand, that certificate is bundled with this version of `gnupg`, and `sks-keyservers.netCA.pem` is indeed present in `/usr/local/share/gnupg`.

I have two problems:

## 1. Keyserver don't work

Trying to do anything against keyserver produces `No route to host`:

```
$ gpg -vvv --debug-all --search-keys [Some KeyID]
gpg: reading options from '/Users/username/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust hashing ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] start
gpg: DBG: chan_6 <- # Home: /Users/username/.gnupg
gpg: DBG: chan_6 <- # Config: /Users/username/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf
gpg: DBG: chan_6 <- OK Dirmngr 2.2.10 at your service
gpg: DBG: connection to the dirmngr established
gpg: DBG: chan_6 -> GETINFO version
gpg: DBG: chan_6 <- D 2.2.10
gpg: DBG: chan_6 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_6 -> KS_SEARCH -- [Some KeyID]
gpg: DBG: chan_6 <- ERR 167804970 No route to host <Dirmngr>
gpg: error searching keyserver: No route to host
gpg: keyserver search failed: No route to host
gpg: DBG: chan_6 -> BYE
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] stop
gpg: keydb: handles=0 locks=0 parse=0 get=0
gpg:        build=0 update=0 insert=0 delete=0
gpg:        reset=0 found=0 not=0 cache=0 not=0
gpg: kid_not_found_cache: count=0 peak=0 flushes=0
gpg: sig_cache: total=0 cached=0 good=0 bad=0
gpg: random usage: poolsize=600 mixed=0 polls=0/0 added=0/0
              outmix=0 getlvl1=0/0 getlvl2=0/0
gpg: secmem usage: 0/32768 bytes in 0 blocks
```

## 2. dirmngr.conf is actually ignored

If I try to use any other keyserver, changing it in `dirmngr.conf` does nothing, but entering it into `gpg.conf`, as in:

```
# gpg.conf
keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net
```

does work, and keyserver operations then run as normal.

It looks like my `dirmngr.conf` is actually ignored and hkps pool is used as built-in default.

Why is `--keyserver` option deprecated for `gpg` and delegated to `dirmngr`, if it doesn't work on the latter but instead still works in the former?

And what is the problem with `hkps`? Is there a way to debug this further?

*EDIT 0: Spelling*

Comment: dirmngr has it's own --debug-level level options too, see `man dirmngr`. Maybe you just need to restart / SIGHUP the dirmngr program... I've no idea why gpg would deprecate --keyserver, or why they started ignoring options like --passphrase and --passphrase-file without special pinentry options too, seems like beta options are getting pushed through before they're stable

Comment: Managed to circumvent "No route to host" with `disable-ipv6` option in `dirmngr.conf` (had to restart `dirmngr` afterward), but then the error just changed to "No data".